# OpenCart - How to remove/disable Add to Cart function until person has logged in?

Tags: php, web, opencart

I need to disable the add to cart button only when a person is not logged in like the hide price is hid until log in, where is the code for this so that can i hide the add to cart button same way until log in?

I am using opencart version 2.0.3.1

Comment: a better approach "redirect the user to the login page if he is not logged in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart is not providing a default functionality. so you will using following condition on every add to cart button.

Eg.

```
<?php if ($logged) { ?> <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?> </button><?php } ?>
```

and assign logged variable in controller file

```
$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

You can use following 'if' condition code for that.

```
<?php if ($logged) { ?>
   ...your add to cart button code here...
<?php } ?>
```